# How to use form controls from a class

Tags: c#, controls

I want to use the controls of a form from a generic class. In VB is very easy but in C# is difficult as I am trying to learn it.
So searching I found an ease answer to this and I am coping here

---

Set the control to public in the designer:

```
  public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Create a new class and for example rename it to exampleClass

```
  public class exampleClass
  {
      public static Form1 frm;
      public static void HideButton()
      {
    frm.button1.Visible = false;
      }
  }
```

Add this after Form1 InitializeComponent:

```
  exampleClass.frm = this;
```

Now you can hide the button from anywhere you want:

```
  exampleClass.HideButton();
```

---

My question now is:
If we want to make more general and pass the control and the status (true/false) to the class method eg

```
 exampleClass.HideButton(Control, Status)
```

How can we do?

Thanks in advance, 
Elias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's straight forward:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public static void HideControl(Control control, bool hide)
    {
        if (control != null) control.Visible = !hide;
    }
}
```

And you call it like

```
ExampleClass.HideControl(frm.Button1, true);
```

---

But after writing this I wonder, why do you need this? If you have your `Button` already, why not simply call

```
frm.Button1.Visible = false;
```

instead of another static method?

Comment: Thanks Rene and all for your help. I use not only the toolbar buttons to enable/disable but I use a lot from all of my forms the status bar in order to display messages. That's why I am using a class with general methods for all controls of the Main MDI Form. THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: @ekekakos best way of thanking on StackOverflow is to accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it as you describe: pass the control and the status to the method as parameters. Don't forget to include: `using System.Windows.Forms;`

```
public class Class2
{
    public static void HideButton(Control c, bool status)
    {
        c.Visible = status;
    }
}
```

and use the external class in the `WinForm` like this:

```
Class2.HideButton(this.button2, false);
```

PS. I misread in the first version. You wanted to have a static method. Changed it

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
public static void HideControl(Control control, bool visible)
{
    control.Visible = visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you have a form called Form1.cs and a class called exampleClass:

In exampleClass (Note: the name of my Form Class = 'Form1'):

```
Form1 ui = new Form1();
ui.button1.Visible = false;
```

In (FormName).Designer.cs so in my case Form1.designer.cs change the appropriate control from 'private' to 'public':

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```